# Database normalization 2NF and 3NF

Tags: database-normalization, 3nf

Assume the relation `Appliance(model, year, price, manufacturer, color)`
with `{model, year}` as a key and following FDs:

```
model -> manufacturer
model, year -> price
manufacturer -> color
```

Find 2NF and 3NF.

My solution was this:
Since  `model -> manufacturer` violates 2NF because of partial dependency, I decomposed Appliance as below:

```
R1(model, manufacturer)
R2(model, year, price)
R3(manufacturer, color)
```

Similarly `model -> manufacturer` and `manufacturer -> color` violates 3NF because of transitive dependency so, I decompose Appliance as below:

```
R1(model, manufacturer)
R2(model, year, price)
R3(model, color)
```

My question is what is wrong with my normalization?

Comment: {model, year} is a CK, so it functionally determines every attribute. So mentioning {model, year} -> price doesn't make sense. Also problem FDs arise from all the the non-trivial FDs that hold but you have only listed *some* of the non-trivial FDs that hold. Also it isn't partial & transitive FDs that are bad, it is *certain* partial & transitive FDs that are bad. And ones that are bad are only bad per a *particular definition*. So quote the definitions you are using. PS We don't get the best 3NF designs by going through 2NF. (Despite what some textbooks say.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your normalization for 2NF is right. You might want to think harder about whether a *relation* violates 2NF or 3NF, or whether a *functional dependency* violates 2NF or 3NF. You say both.

In your 2NF decomposition, R1, R2, and R3 are in 5NF. (So, by definition, they're also in 3NF and 2NF.)

For 3NF, you've lost the FD `manufacturer -> color`. So that's wrong.

In the real world, normalizing a relation like "Appliance" *might* result in more than one 5NF decomposition.

Comment: In my solution, R3 differs in 2NF and 3NF. Also, I meant to say that FDs violates 2NF and 3NF.

Comment: @NimitPatel: You're right. I misread your decomposition for 3NF. But that decomposition is wrong; you've lost the FD manufacturer -> color.

Comment: I agree my decomposition is wrong, 3NF should preserve FDs. So, then `R1(model, manufacturer, color)` and `R2(model, year, price)` would be in 3NF ? Thanks!

Comment: @NimitPatel: No, that would leave either a transitive dependency or a partial key dependency in R1, depending on what you decide the key ought to be. Your decomposition for 2NF is correct for both 2NF and 3NF. (Because R1, R2, and R3 are all in 5NF.)